# Apple API to check if an iOS application is purchased by certain Apple ID

Tags: ios, apple-id

Does anyone know if there is an API or some kind of service that will allow you to check if certain iOS application is purchased by certain Apple ID?

Here is the thing. I have an iOS application which uses some services. App is available as free and paid (paid allows you some extra features). But the trick is I can't know if an app is actually purchased or it's on jailbroken device.

Al those checks on an iOS app are not to be trusted since client can not be trusted, so I would like to make that check server side.

So my idea was to check if that app is purchased by given Apple ID to make sure that it's legit.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Ante.

Comment: I hope not.  There are far more ways to abuse such a feature than there are benefits.  (Also, a jailbroken device and a purchased app are not mutually exclusive.)

Comment: @PhillipMills agree on both of that. But still, I can never be sure if an app is legally purchased or illegally installed on jailbroken device :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great WWDC session on this. It talks about receipts from the app store: Session 308 from 2013 "Using receipts to protect your digital sales". This is interesting also if you do not have in-app purchases.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/308/

Comment: Particularly, the bit on server-to-server validation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Comment: According to this, I will be able to check if receipt is valid which I suppose should be sufficient enough to run this, since it is the only way of doing this. I'll mark this answer as correct. Thanks Joride and also @CraigOtis